# Apply LUT using GDCM on DICOM File

Tags: c#, dicom, gdcm

I have an RLE compressed DICOM file that has `PALETTE_COLOR` photometric interpretation. Using GDCM, I can get the fragment using this code:

```
gdcm.ImageReader imagereader = new gdcm.ImageReader();
imagereader.SetFileName(fileName);
if (imagereader.Read())
  {
  DataElement compressedPixelData = imagereader.GetFile().GetDataSet().GetDataElement(Helper.PIXEL_DATA);
  SequenceOfFragments sf = compressedPixelData.GetSequenceOfFragments();
  if (sf == null) throw new Exception("Cannot get fragments!");
  Fragment frag = sf.GetFragment((uint)frameNumber);
  uint bufLen = Convert.ToUInt32(frag.GetByteValue().GetLength().toString());
  byte[] buffer = new byte[bufLen];
  frag.GetByteValue().GetBuffer(buffer, bufLen);
  }
```

Now I'm trying to create an image from the buffer. Since it's `PALETTE_COLOR`, I have to apply the LUT to the buffer. I use this code :

```
gdcm.LookupTable lut = imagereader.GetImage().GetLUT();

int size = ImageWidth * ImageHeight * 3;
byte[] decodedBuffer = new byte[size];

bool worked = lut.Decode(decodedBuffer, (uint)size, buffer, (uint)bufLen);

if (worked)
   return decodedBuffer;
else
   return buffer;
```

The decodedBuffer size is `Width * Height * 3` since I expect RGB pixel after applying LUT. But the resulting image is incorrect.

If I use `ImageApplyLookupTable` class, I can display the image correctly.

I don't want to use `ImageApplyLookupTable` class since it will decode the entire image (all fragments!) into raw RGB pixels and consume a lot of memory. I want to decode framge by frame to minimize memory usage.

Could you point me to right direction on how to use `gdcm.LookupTable` class correctly to decode a frame at a time ? The sample file I used is [here.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45574079/PAL-8_RLE.dcm)

UPDATED: Using `ImageRegionReader` worked for the 8 bit PALETTE COLOR, but didn't work for 16 bit, could you check why? I have the sample [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45574079/PAL-16_RLE.dcm) for 16 bit.

Comment: You should check [ExtractImageRegionWithLUT.cs](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/2.6/html/ExtractImageRegionWithLUT_8cs-example.xhtml)

Comment: @malat - see my update, it worked for 8 bit, but not for 16 bit, any clue?

Comment: In the above given example decodedBuffer array is not proper. All array values are coming zero. I am working with 8 bit PALETTE COLOR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GDCM comes with a bunch of examples, in your case I would suggest you start reading: [ExtractImageRegionWithLUT.cs](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/2.6/html/ExtractImageRegionWithLUT_8cs-example.xhtml).

The code is pretty silly since it will write over and over the extracted frames over the previous one. But anyway this should give you the basic idea. Here is what I did over here:

First make sure your C# examples are build (I use make in my case):

```
$ make GDCMCSharpExample
```

then:

```
$ ExtractImageRegionWithLUT.exe PAL-16_RLE.dcm
```

On UNIX this will create a raw file, that you can convert back to DICOM using `gdcmimg`:

```
$ gdcmimg --depth 16 --spp 3 --size 800,600 /tmp/frame_rgb.raw /tmp/frame_rgb.raw.dcm
```

You can then simply view it:

```
$ gdcmviewer /tmp/frame_rgb.raw.dcm
```

You can even use the following to convince yourself:

```
$ gdcmimg -C 1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.3.1 --depth 16 --spp 3 --size 800,600 /tmp/frame_rgb.raw /tmp/frame_rgb.raw.dcm
```

Comment: sorry, it worked for 16 bit now. Previously I forgot to recalculate the value from 16 bit to 24 bit. My viewer only support 24 bit.